# Any good place to review/workshop homebrew for 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, homebrew-review

So, I’ve been doing a homebrew campaign for awhile now and some of my players are starting to suggest I look into publishing some of the stuff on places like dmsguild, but I’m not persuaded any of my stuff is ready for that. In the meantime, are there any good sites or forums where I could share subclasses and such, not for specific questions but general opinions or feedback?

Any suggestions are much appreciated and have my thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a kind of question we don't handle, but instead direct to our list of RPG [forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137), which I suppose (or at least hope) works for you :)